# TensorFlow Learning Weights of Linear Model

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to learn the weights of a linear transformation model in TensorFlow. It seems that the training loss is very low, yet the weights produced are very different from the actual ones used in the transformation.

When I do this very same thing except using scalars for `W` and `b`, I am able to recover the original parameters, but when I extend it to matrix multiplication as below, the "learned" parameters differ only slightly from what they were initialized to (random), and are no where near the actual values used (`_W`, `_b`). How can I get this model to report the learned values of the linear transformation?

```
def get_linear_relationship(x_shape, y_shape):
    W = np.random.random((y_shape[0], x_shape[0]))
    b = np.random.random(y_shape)
    x = np.random.random(x_shape)
    y = np.matmul(W, x) + b
    return x, y, W, b


def linear_model():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        x_shape = (3, 1)
        y_shape = (3, 1)
        _x, _y, _W, _b = get_linear_relationship(x_shape, y_shape)

        W = tf.Variable(np.random.random((y_shape[0], x_shape[0])), dtype=tf.float32)
        b = tf.Variable(np.random.random(y_shape), dtype=tf.float32)
        x = tf.placeholder(shape=x_shape, dtype=tf.float32)
        model = tf.matmul(W, x) + b

        y = tf.placeholder(shape=y_shape, dtype=tf.float32)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(model - y))

        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
        train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

        # initialization
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)

        result = sess.run(loss, {x: _x, y: _y})
        print("Random: ", result)

        for i in range(1000):
            sess.run(train, {x: _x, y: _y})

        print("Actual W, b:\n", _W, _b)
        print("Learned:\n", sess.run([W, b]))

        trained_result = sess.run(loss, {x: _x, y: _y})
        print("Training loss: ", trained_result)
```

Here is an example output:

```
Random:  0.854376
Actual W, b:
 [[ 0.68397062  0.48808535  0.0248331 ]
 [ 0.15806422  0.37479114  0.1709631 ]
 [ 0.45631878  0.7785539   0.69242146]] [[ 0.92418495]
 [ 0.41903298]
 [ 0.92627156]]
Learned:
 [array([[ 0.17904782,  0.58858037,  0.05749775],
       [ 0.63658452,  0.47282287,  0.40709457],
       [ 0.05679467,  0.62718385,  0.39558661]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.87702203],
       [ 0.23417197],
       [ 1.13123035]], dtype=float32)]
Training loss:  0.00073651
```

As you can see, the variables `W` and `b` in the model are nothing like those that are actually found in the transformation from `_x` to `_y`, despite a large reduction in the loss function. Why are they different and how can I get learned parameters that approximate the true ones?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are only training using the same data point over and over. Since the model only has a single data point from which to learn the linear relationship (which has several degrees of freedom), it has no hope of matching/extrapolating any data points beyond that single one. To fix this simply, give the model more example of transformed data points to learn from. Modify your training loop as so

```
    for i in range(10000):
        _x = np.random.random(x_shape)
        sess.run(train, {x: _x, y: np.matmul(_W, _x) + _b})
```

And you should be able to recover the original `W` and `b` parameters.